# How to fix Error English Language Loading in Spacy

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, spacy

I am using Anaconda Spyder

I installed Spacy through

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

Looks fine

I now try to install English Language

I used

```
python -m spacy download en

python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

I got this results

```
Collecting en_core_web_lg==2.1.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.1.0/en_core_web_lg-2.1.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_lg==2.1.0
  Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.1.0/en_core_web_lg-2.1.0.tar.gz (826.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 826.9MB 3.6MB/s
Installing collected packages: en-core-web-lg
  Running setup.py install for en-core-web-lg ... done
Successfully installed en-core-web-lg-2.1.0
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
```

but when i try to use

```
import spacy
spacy.load("en")
```

I get this error

```
runfile('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02/NLP02.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-ae15dd4e45dd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02/NLP02.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02/NLP02.py", line 2, in <module>
    spacy.load("en")

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 27, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 139, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

and by using

```
import spacy
spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
```

I get this error

```
runfile('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02/NLP02.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-ae15dd4e45dd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02/NLP02.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/OneDrive/__PhD/Code/NLP/NLP02/NLP02.py", line 2, in <module>
    spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 27, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 139, in load_model
    raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

How to fix these error so i can start using Spacy?

Comment: May be you can fix by [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3113)